# Method that returns null is causing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

I wrote this method:

```
@Override
    protected String call() {
        if (list != null) {
            int s = list.size();
            Metadata metadata;
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                try {
                    File f = list.get(i);
                    metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(f);
                    // obtain the Exif directory
                    ExifSubIFDDirectory directory = metadata.getDirectory(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);
                    // query the tag's value
                    Date date = directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);
                    if (date != null) {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        System.out.println("File: " + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\tDATETIME_ORIGINAL: " + sdf.format(date));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("File: " + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\tDATETIME_ORIGINAL: no data!");
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                } finally {
                    updateProgress(i + 1, s);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Method directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL) can sometimes return null:
[Source](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/source/browse/Source/com/drew/metadata/Directory.java?r=efcf135e5cb7b9947812054acd845048f0b0ef9e#723)

Problem is that by just calling that method java throws Null Pointer Exception, so I cannot test it with date!=null. NetBeans also reports "Dereferencing possible null pointer" hint. I do not understand why this happens. Why I'm not able to store null value in some object and test it? Even if I don't store value in variable, that method still causes the same exception when returning null.

Comment: On which line do you get this error or warning?

Comment: On this line:
Date date = directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);

I even tried to call only method without storing null value anywhere:
directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);
and still get the same exception. That confuses me a lot.

Comment: That would indicate that directory is null.  So check for that possibility and either skip it or report an appropriate failure result.

Comment: You are correct, variable directory can sometimes be null. Thank you for the answer. Somehow I presumed that it cannot be null, and that problem is in parsing date when there is no tag. I feel so stupid now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution to this problem would be using another catch statement for NullPointerException, then calling the code you would call if the Date was null. You would also have to move variable "File f" out of the try-statement block to ensure access in the catch.

Example,

```
catch(NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println("File: " + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\tDATETIME_ORIGINAL: no data!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I know that, but I want to avoid it. What bothers me is that I can do this without problems:
`private static String test(){
    return null;
}
...
String a = test();
        if(a != null){
            System.out.println("Not null");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Null");
        }`

Comment: You're getting the warning "Dereferencing possible null pointer" because there is a possibility that your variable "directory" is null. If "directory" is null, then calling the function getDate() would cause the error. I am not sure if that helps. Try stepping through the program in debug and make sure your variables "f", "metadata", and "directory" are being properly declared.

Comment: You are right, variable directory is sometimes null. I can't believe that I was that stupid. I will accept your answer because it is correct way to catch this kind of exception. Thank you.

Comment: Catching a NPE is like catching "Exception" and running away from the problem.. How dum